# Buscar conteúdo de uma td a partir de uma class

Tags: javascript

Tenho as seguintes linhas dentro de uma tabela:

```html
<table id="table_marcas">
    <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td class="template">Óleos</td>
        <td class="template">Veículos</td>
        <td class="template">Óleos</td>
    </tr>
.....
</table>
```

Estas linhas são geradas dinamicamente no servidor de acordo com algumas condições, e podem existir ou não existir no HTML final. O que eu procuro, é ir buscar o conteúdo da *class* "template", e depois verificar se existe algum igual a "Óleos".

Comment: Teria como você explicar melhor essa parte de **dinâmica**? A estrutura da tabela é alterada ou somente os valores? É após o carregamento da página ou após algum evento, como um click em um botão?

Comment: @Randrade, sim a estrutura pode ser alterada, podem ser removidas linhas, ou adicionadas novas linhas. Acontece durante o carregamento da página

Comment: Se é durante o carregamento, o código da resposta abaixo deve lhe atender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar `getElementsByClassName` para buscar todos os elementos que possuem essa classe, então verificar o conteúdo dela:

```js
console.log(verificarElemento('Óleos'));

function verificarElemento(nome) {
  var tds = document.getElementsByClassName("template");
  for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    if (tds[i].innerHTML == nome)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="template">Óleos</td>
    <td class="template">Veículos</td>
    <td class="template">Óleos</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: é isso que precisava. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode usar jQuery para fazer o for somente nos elemento que vc quer

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#table_marcas tr td.template").each(function(x,e){
     alert($(e).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_marcas">
    <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td class="template">Óleos</td>
        <td class="template">Veículos</td>
        <td class="template">Óleos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td class="template2">Óleos2</td>
        <td class="template2">Veículos2</td>
        <td class="template2">Óleos2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: O AP (autor da pergunta) tagou somente javascript @RafaelLilo.